# Using console.log() to display Object as string returns [object Object]

Tags: javascript

I tried to pull some data from a json file and so I used console.log() to test it. To make sure it's easier to read, I used template literals to highlight it with some extra information. However, I keep getting *[object, Object]*. I assumed that I failed to pull the data and inspected the json file data for hours. Eventually, I found out I require the data correctly but it was console.log() failed me.

So I thought it's a template literals thing, so I tried the other two ways and they still got the same results. Why?

```
var obj = {
    "date": "Sun Jun 14 21:36:17 UTC 2009",
    "user": "captain_pete",
    "tweet": "Reading the tweets coming out of Iran... The whole thing is terrifying and incredibly sad..."
}

console.log(obj)
console.log('Obj1: ' + obj)
console.log('Obj2: ' + obj.toString()
console.log(`Obj3: ${obj}`)
```

Output:

```
{date: 'Sun Jun 14 21:36:17 UTC 2009', user: 'captain_pete', tweet:'Reading the tweets coming out of Iran... The whole thing is terrifying and incredibly sad...'} 
Obj1: [object Object]
Obj2: [object Object] 
Obj3: [object Object]
```

Comment: You are trying to convert it to a string by using it in a template literal or string concatenation, which just gives you what you are seeing. If you want to log the object and navigate through its properties log it directly, eg `console.log('some text', obj)` note `obj` is being passed as a different argument

Comment: If you want print a single property in an object, `console.log('Obj1: ' + obj.date)` or `console.log('Obj1: ' + obj["date"])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last three lines are all invoking [`Object.toString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString) on `obj`, which by default returns a string in the form of `[object type]`.

If you want the object as a string, you can use `JSON.stringify`:

```js
var obj = {
    "date": "Sun Jun 14 21:36:17 UTC 2009",
    "user": "captain_pete",
    "tweet": "Reading the tweets coming out of Iran... The whole thing is terrifying and incredibly sad..."
}

Object.prototype.toString = function(){
  return JSON.stringify(this)
}

console.log(obj)
console.log('Obj1: ' + obj)
console.log('Obj2: ' + obj.toString())
console.log(`Obj3: ${obj}`)
```

Comment: Is this the same as type conversion like number + string ends up as string?

Comment: @MeoW Yes, it is.